# C# DateTime Conditioning if the Value is Not 5 and 20 On the Day

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm creating some payment scheduling using datagrid. My scenario is, when the day of DateTime is MM/4/YYYY,MM/3/YYYY,MM/2/YYYY,MM/1/YYYY etc. and MM/21/YYYY,MM/18//YYYY etc, the date must be outputted as 5 and 20 prior to the payment schedule.

I'm using a for loop here when the button "Execute" is Clicked

```
private void execute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
int count;
int loop_number = 8;

// Example I pick August 5
var fromDate = date_from.Value; // This the datetimepicker on the toolbox

    for (count = 0; count < loop_number ; count++) {
        // The output will be shown in the datagrid with a name of "dgv_result"

            fromDate = fromDate.AddDays(15);

            dgv_result.Rows[count].Cells[0].Value = fromDate;

    }
}
```

The Output should be like this below

```
08/5/2015
08/20/2015
// The Problem is, aug has 31 so the result will be 9/4/2015
// But instead, it should be 5
09/5/2015
// Same thing with 9/19/2015, the result must be 
09/20/2015
... // So on and so forth
```

[image]

#### NOTE: Just look on the date only

This is the loop for the screenshot above
    var fromDate = date_from.Value;
    int count;

```
for (count = 0; count < Loop_number; count++) {
 dgv_result.Rows.Add(1);
 ...

 dgv_result.Rows[count].Cells[0].Value = fromDate;
}
```

Comment: where are you giving your condition of 4 and/or 19?

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? What do you mean by day is 4 and 19? Do you mean 4 or 19? I.e. increment the day by one if it is 4 or 19, so 4 becomes and 19 becomes 20?

Comment: Sure sir. I'll edit it

Comment: Sir. I'm done editing it.

Comment: @mark - I don't think you need to call anyone "sir" here unless you know that they've been knighted by royalty. ;-)

Comment: sir @Enigmativity Haha I'm so sorry. Here in our country, we use "sir/ma'am" for people who deserve some respect and base on their position :)

Comment: @mark - I understand, but none of the normal social cues (age, position, role, appearance, etc) apply here to determine when to say "sir"/"madam" so it does come across as a little supercilious. I'd suggest you just treat everyone here as equals.

Comment: Aw. Haha honestly sir @Enigmativity, I'm not comfortable to not say "Sir" to address one person in a forum. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
int loop_number = 8;
var fromDate = date_from.Value; // This the datetimepicker on the toolbox

for (int count = 0; count < loop_number ; count++) 
{
    var currentDate = fromDate.AddMonths(count);
    if (currentDate.Day <= 5)
    {
        currentDate = new DateTime(currentDate.Year, currentDate.Month, 5);
    } 
    else 
    {
        currentDate = new DateTime(currentDate.Year, currentDate.Month, 20);
    }

    dgv_result.Rows[count].Cells[0].Value = currentDate;
}
```

Comment: No sir, the values of date is wrong. It turns the 8 loop with the same date. :(

Comment: @mark I don't understand clear what you want to get. can you show example? simple table with output

Comment: Sir I added some screenshot of my app :)

Comment: Sir I have also a problem, You see the date, I've chosen 8/5/2015 but the first execute of the loop is, 8/20/2015 it must be something like 8/5/2015 on the first count of the loop :)

Comment: Any idea sir? Why I get that issue?

Comment: Why the first count is not the value choosen in the datepicker? :( It must be 8/5/2015 on the first count then followed by 8/20/2015. But as you see above, the first count is 8/20/2015 which is wrong. :(

Comment: @mark i forgot to replace one `fromDate` to `currentDate` in condition, check again. now you will get 8/5/2015

Comment: Okay sir. I think its not an issue. :) Because my var fromDate is from my  dateTimePicker :)

Comment: Sir, do you have an idea? Why the first count is not the value choosen in the datepicker? :( It must be 8/5/2015 on the first count then followed by 8/20/2015. But as you see above, the first count is 8/20/2015 which is wrong. :(

Comment: @mark in my code it wiil be 8/5/2015, because `Day <= 5`

Comment: Yes sir. But I think I have a problem in my loop. :( Sir please check my updated for loop above. :) I'll post it. I think my looping is wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87676/discussion-between-backs-and-mark).

Answer (score 1):

mark, your problem is still not entirely clear but here is what I assume: Let's say the user picks August 16 2015, then you want to print out Aug 5, Aug 20, Sep 5, Sep 20, Oct 5, Oct 20, Nov 5 and Nov 20.

The following code should do just that. Please keep in mind that adding 15 days twice to a day will not always give you the 5th and the 20th the following month (unless the current month has 30 days).

```
// loops reduced to 4 because two values are filled per iteration
int loop_number = 4;
// normalize chosen date to known day of month, the 1st
DateTime firstOfMonth = new DateTime(fromDate.Year, fromDate.Month, 1);

for (count = 0; count < loop_number; count++)
{
    // calculate 5th of month
    DateTime schedule1 = firstOfMonth.AddDays(4);
    dgv_result.Rows[count].Cells[0].Value = schedule1;

    // calculate 20th of month
    DateTime schedule2 = firstOfMonth.AddDays(19);
    dgv_result.Rows[count].Cells[0].Value = schedule2;

    firstOfMonth = firstOfMonth.AddMonths(1);
}
```

Comment: Sir please check my screenshot above :) Thank you sir.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `15` days into fromDate in every iteration

Try this

```
private void execute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int count;
    int loop_number = 8;    
    // Example I pick August 5
    var fromDate = date_from.Value; // This the datetimepicker on the toolbox
    for (count = 0; count < loop_number ; count++) 
    {
        dgv_result.Rows[count].Cells[0].Value = fromDate.AddDays(15);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir, I just need the date, because I have different codes for those date.

Comment: I just make 8 loop as my example.